# How do I understand if Linux actually merged two pages?

Tags: caching, paging, sharing, mmap, flush

I've been trying to implement the attack described in this paper: https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/448.pdf . Unfortunately there is no source code nor enough details on how some very low-level details work.

For example they state that `mmap`ping the executable of a process P1 in the virtual space of another process P2 makes the kernel (supposedly) merge the `.text` segment of P1 with the same `.text` segment that has been `mmap`ped by P1 at the physical memory level (which to P2, of course, is just random data in memory, not an actual `.text` segment). But how can I make sure this actually happens?

Let's take address `a` in P1's `.text`. Its content in P2's virtual space will be at address `a*` (belonging to the `mmap`ped space) with `a` != `a*` (obviously), even though they (should) both point to the same address in the physical memory. If I `clflush` `a*` how can I make sure I'm also flushing `a` (since the cache is mapped to the physical memory)? In other words: is there a way to know whether or not Linux has merged the two pages referred by `a` and `a*`?

Thank you in advance.

PS: I know you can't translate a virtual address into a physical address in user space but I can't write a driver or anything like that.

PPS: this is the excerpt of the paper that describes the `mmap`ping phase (section 4):

`The spy and the victim execute as two
processes within that system. To achieve sharing, the spy
mmaps the victim’s executable file into the spy’s virtual
address space. As the Linux loader maps executable files
into the process when executing them, the spy and the
victim share the memory image of the mapped file.`